# How to iterate nested list in tcl?

Tags: tcl

There is a nested list x in tcl

```
set x {{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3}}
```

How to iterate over and print all the elements in this nested list?

Comment: What did you try and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to extend Dinesh's answer to make it truly recursive:

```
set x {{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3} {4 {F G}}}; # Have added one more element

proc printListElem {myList {level 1}} {
    foreach elem $myList {
        puts "[string repeat "+" $level] $elem"
        if {[llength $elem] > 1} {
            printListElem $elem [expr {$level + 1}]
        }
    }
}
```

printListElem $x

```
+ A 0
++ A
++ 0
+ B 1
++ B
++ 1
+ C 2
++ C
++ 2
+ D 3
++ D
++ 3
+ 4 {F G}
++ 4
++ F G
+++ F
+++ G
```

Comment: @Dinesh, do you want to take this in your answer?

Comment: Wow!!! It looks great. Better be a stand-alone wiki answer. :). Actually, I was thinking of making it to more robust by means of supporting more number of nested levels in list. Let me update it in my answer. Hope that it should be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I see people trying to iterate recursively and come up with generic solutions, and I'm pretty sure that some may not agree with this, but the answer to the question "How to iterate over and print all the elements in **this** nested list?" is pretty straightforward.

The list contains 4 elements "A 1", "B 2", "C 3", "D 4", so the answer would be:

```
% set x {{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3}}
{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3}

% foreach item $x {
    puts $item
}
A 0
B 1
C 2
D 3
```

Presuming that one would want to do something with the individual values then they can be split out using [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lindex.htm) or [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm), e.g.

```
% foreach item $x {
    lassign $item char num
    puts "char = $char, num = $num"
}
char = A, num = 0
char = B, num = 1
char = C, num = 2
char = D, num = 3
```

The [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm) can also take multiple values so it would also be possible to do it this way:

```
foreach item $x {
    foreach {char num} $item {
        puts "char = $char, num = $num"
    }
}
```

In practice one wouldn't have random levels of nested lists to store useful data, but if one actually happens to have such data then it might be worth looking into [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm).

As an example:

```
 % set x {A {B 2} C {D {E 5}} F 6}
 A {B 2} C {D {E 5}} F 6
 % dict get $x A
 B 2
 % dict get $x A B
 2
 % dict get $x C D E
 5
 % dict get $x F
 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set x {{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3} {6 {F G}}}

set y {{{{1 2 {3 4}}}}}

array set myarr {}
set count 0
proc printListElem {myList} {
    global myarr count
    for {set i 0} {$i <[llength $myList]} {incr i} {
        set currentElem [lindex $myList $i]
        if {![info exists myarr($count,${currentElem})]} {
            incr count
            set myarr($count,${currentElem}) 1
            printListElem $currentElem
        } else {
            incr count -1
            break
        }
    }
}

printListElem $y
foreach idx [lsort [array names myarr]] {
    lassign [split $idx ,] key value
    puts "[string repeat "+" $key]$value"
}
```

This one will work for all nested levels of lists and the output will be shown something like,

```
+{{1 2 {3 4}}}
++{1 2 {3 4}}
+++1 2 {3 4}
++++1
++++2
++++3 4
+++++3
+++++4
```

The number of `+` present in here will represent the nested level of list elements. (Thanks to Mr.Glenn for idea). This might not be an efficient, but it can be done in this way too.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the list depth, we can just nest some `foreach` calls:

```
foreach a $x {
    foreach b $a {
        puts "--> $b"
    }
}
```

But a general “iterate over all possible nested lists” doesn't exist in Tcl, as the concept is incompatible with Tcl's type model. You literally shouldn't think about values in a way that makes that a sensible question to ask about. You don't build *arbitrary* trees: you build *specific* trees where the levels are meaningful to the problem at hand.

(The key problem is that `red hot cat` is simultaneously a 3 item list and an 11 character string.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to completely lose all track of nesting levels then you can use this approach to completely collapse all nested list levels (except that if **{}** are used within a string value in the list those will also be obliterated

```
set x {{A 0} {B 1} {C 2} {D 3} {6 {F G}}} 
set xn [string map {"{" "" "}" ""} $x] 


puts [join $xn "\n"]
```